# How can I set up a Lucene index in Sitecore that handles security correctly?

Tags: security, lucene, sitecore

I have a number of different roles in Sitecore.  And I have set security permissions on my content items so that different roles can only access certain content items.  It seems that Lucene will just index all of the content.  And when I query Lucene it doesn't pay any attention to the security.  Is there any way to get Lucene to only return items that the current Extranet user has access to?

Thanks,
Corey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to my knowledge. But when working through the Hits collection, you would normally have a loop similar to this:

```cs
for ( int i = 0; i < hits.Length() && i < Context.Current.Settings.MaxSearchResultsToProcess; i++ )
{
    Item item = Index.GetItem( hits.Doc( i ), Context.Current.Database );
    if ( item != null )
    {
        indexResultater.Add( item );
    }
}
```

And since this runs in context of your current user, no results would be added to your results if the user cannot access them.

Comment: Actually in my code I do it a little differently.  Instead of iterating through thousands of results, I only iterate through the current page of items.  So if my search returned 1,475 hits and I was on page 2 of the result set then I would only pull hits 11-20.  However I suppose I could try it the way that you suggested.  It just means that I would have to always iterate through all 1,475 hits and then get just the ones I have access to.  Then after that I could just return items 11-20.  Hopefully it won't be too slow.

Comment: In reality, it isn't usually too bad. A couple of things you can consider, is not returning more than YYY results anyway from a search. 1475 would be what I consider too many, I usually never ask Lucene to process more than around 200-300 hits for any given query. Sitecore's Item cache will help you (a lot) for subsequent page requests, and finally you do have the option of caching the result for page browsing.