# Sitecore 7: Searching with userrights

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

There seems to be quite alot of pages about Lucene and searching in Sitecore out there, some more updated than others, and frankly im getting abit confused about where I need to put in my efforts.

So my question is, what would be the best approach when integrating a sitewide search functionality, with the following requirements:

- Results must respect user access rights (eg. HasReadAcces via the SC security model)
- Results must include items, with layout details referencing different datasources (eg.components with a datasource).
- The results must include a "teaser/snippet" text.
- Include some sort of relevance/scoring priority.

Answer (score 0):

When researching you will want to concentrate on the new `Sitecore.ContentSearch` posts rather than the old `Sitecore.Search` posts (although both will work in v7) as this has more of the new functionality in it.

- You may want to look at this post about setting up access rights by
  storing values in the index:

  [Indexing Sitecore Item security and restricting returned search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683487/indexing-sitecore-item-security-and-restricting-returned-search-results/16686827#16686827)
- Im not quite sure what you mean about "with layout details
  referencing different datasources" why would you want this
  information in your search index ?
- All fields are indexed and you can store whatever field, from your item, you want in the index, so when outputting the result item you could truncate after a certain number of words or characters, alternatively you could make a template field called 'Snippet' that editors would produce and display that with each result.
- With all search indexes scoring is what its designed to do, the default sort order is by relevance based on internal scoring of that item to the terms you searched on. You can influence that scoring by use of `boosting` in certain ways.