# Sitecore Item Buckets When User Doesn't Have Read Access to All Items

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

If a user is searching a **sitecore bucket**, and they do not have **read access** to all of the items within the bucket, then issues occur when they search.

**Example:**

Say there are 1000 items returned in a bucket search and the user only has read access to 100 of them. What ends up happening is it still says "Your search has returned 1000 items". Worse yet, all of the items that they do not have read access to still show up in the list but are blank.

This creates the illusion that no results were returned. When, in reality, the user doesn't have access to any of the items given a certain page index/size.

Has anyone run in to this issue before? I'm guessing Sitecore is doing post-search processing on the items which is causing the items to be found in the search, but not displayed.

**My Thoughts:**

One possible solution I was thinking about is tapping in to the correct Sitecore pipeline and adjusting the Lucene HitCollector to verify user security. If I can find the correct pipeline, this would resolve the issue, but I'm wondering if there is a better way?

I would much rather write code more specific to Sitecore buckets. Such as code that adds a lucene query term (search a custom role field or something similar) and then have it auto-added to the search based on the current user's role.

Comment: duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683487/indexing-sitecore-item-security-and-restricting-returned-search-results#16686827

Comment: This is likely a Sitecore 7 bug. What you should do is open up a Sitecore Support Ticket and give them all of the information, and they will get back to you with a workaround (if necessary) and will add the bug to the list of those to be fixed in the next release (if it is in fact a reproducible bug).

Comment: Christian: The issue is different (I think?): extranet content vs sitecore CMS internal issues. However, the root cause seems to be the same. I believe the fix in the other post, if tweaked, would provide a temporary solution (perhaps permanent). Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Zach: I will open a ticket with Sitecore. If they provide a workaround and/or add to fixes in the next release I will report that here.