# How to work with Sitecore Content Search and Page Editor

Tags: lucene, sitecore

I rewrote a news application (overview + detail) from Fast-Query to Content Search. The performance gains were enormous, but i see some possible limitations, for which i don't know to handle in conjunction with the Page Editor.

1. When i use a fast query, i get an instance of a news even if there isn't a language version yet. In Lucene, i cannot find a result (because i filter for the language) and therefore the news detail is missing in the overview in the particular language.

**EDIT for question 1**

Lets assume that we have a solution with two languages (English and German). I have an item which currently only exist in a single english version. When i'm on an overview page in German and want to find this item with an fast query (the query does not matter), i will get this item back. In the wrong version, but i get it back. Now if i'm in Page Editor, i can go to this item and edit this in German, even if there is no version yet. The first click on the save button will create the first version for me.

When i want to find the item trough the Content Search, my natural way of query it is by making the same filter (probably by template, path and some channeling or whatever) AND a filter by the language property of the SearchResultItem, since i don't want multiple results for the same item. But since there is only a english version yet, the index only contains a single result in english and because of the language filter, i cannot find this item to call GetItem on it.

Since writing this question initially, i see two approaches to get around this:

a) Remove the language filter in Page Editor mode and filter it afterwards somehow (I don't know whether i'm able to get an item which i can edit in Page Editor in the German language)

b) Create a Page Editor specific master search index which holds an entry for all languages in the solution for every item, even if there isn't any in the specific language. I can add a computed field to indicate, whether this result is a real item version or not to filter at some point if necessary. Probably i'm able go call GetItem on this and enable Page Editor capabilities.

2. With lucene, i cannot find the detail item in a (currently) non-existing language version when i want to resolve it by it's display name trough Lucene (because there is no language version indexed yet).

**EDIT for question 2**

This goes hand in hand with question 1

3. In relation with Workflows, i see possible struggles with the Version which is indexed. Is the first Version in index, before you approve the version? Otherwise the overview has no chance to show this item till it is approved in Content Editor.

Has anybody used the Content Search for Page Editor relevant actions and has some advice how to get around such problems?

Comment: What do you mean by "When i use a fast query, i get an instance of a news even if there isn't a language version yet"
Do you make a language fallback ?

Comment: No i mean when i create an item in a specific language (German for example), i can make a fast query to get this item when the current context language is English. When i set this item as Context Item, in Page Editor i can edit this Item in English and on save, it will get it's first English Version. When i use a Content Search with Language Filter to English, i cannot find this Item since it does not exist in the index for this language.

Comment: Could you post you code (Before/After), i don't think this is related to Fast query or Lucene in general

Comment: Sounds like you need to expand your Lucene query to include returning items that have the fallback language when there is no match for the desired language. For example if the fallback language was English then something on the lines of: language == "de" || language == "en". That way your result set will not only be limited to the desired language. If you can post your current queries, then we can probably help better.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issues with Sitecore 7, and while I don't have the ultimate solution for you, hopefully you will find the following information helpful.

I can't word my answer any better than this post: http://thegrumpycoder.com/post/75524076869/sitecore-content-search-beware-of-the-context

With Sitecore ContentSearch you are choosing which search index you would like to use. You are likely using **sitecore_master_index** when in Page Editor / Preview mode, and **sitecore_web_index** on the published site. As the web database only has one version of each item, you don't need to worry about their being multiple versions in the index. However sitecore_master_index will by default index **all** versions of an item in all languages. You can then potentially see items showing up multiple times in your listings components if you're not careful.

Sitecore 7 has a field **"_latestversion"** which you can add to all your queries, but it isn't reliable for a couple of reasons:

1. The latest version isn't necessarily the correct one, taking into account things like publishing restrictions and what date you have selected in the "Experience" view.
2. Due to a bug I have often been able to cause there to be more than one version of an item in the index where _latestversion is 1. Not after a complete rebuild, but after an edit or two. I saw this in Sitecore 7.0 and I'm not sure if it's been fixed yet.

Read http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/04/Sitecore-7-Inbound-and-Outbound-Filter-Pipelines.aspx for more information on how you can use **"Inbound filters"** to ensure only the latest version makes it into the master index, but bear in mind that doesn't really solve the core issue in my opinion as the latest version isn't necessarily the correct one.

So taking this, and the fact that you need language fallbacks, you should probably **not** filter these results out at the Lucene level, but do the necessary magic yourself in code. This would need to:

- Group versions together by their items
- Choose the right version based on the current language, date, security and workflow
- Apply your desired fallback logic if said version isn't found
- Somehow work in pagination into this in a way which performs well

I also feel the following SO question is relevant:
[Indexing Sitecore Item security and restricting returned search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683487/indexing-sitecore-item-security-and-restricting-returned-search-results) - something else which can catch you out when you expect the Search API to work exactly in the same way as the Query API.

I'd be interested to know your thoughts and if you ever find a better solution!  Thanks, Steve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Steve. I was aware of the _latestversion and implemented this already. But because of your link i'm now aware about the pitfalls of this field! The context stuff is pretty obvious to me (painfully branded by Sitecore ;)). About the language stuff: I don't need a fallback. I edited my answer to try to clarify what my problem is.