# Does Sitecore Search TotalSearchResults property take item security in to account?

Tags: c#, solr, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.5

I am using Sitecore 7.5 and SOLR 4.7 and I am noticing that the `TotalSearchResults` property seems to ignore item security.

I perform a search, skip to the proper page and only take the amount needed for the page and the `TotalSearchResults` value is `31`.  However the `Results` themselves are zero (which is correct).

In my Sitecore implementation there are 31 matches for the search, but all of them are restricted by security and should not be accessible by the anonymous user.  Is this right?  I feel like I am missing something.

```
public static SearchResults<myCustomSearchResultItem> SearchContent(string searchTerm, int currentPage, int pageSize, string indexName) {
  using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName).CreateSearchContext(SearchSecurityOptions.EnableSecurityCheck)) {
  var query = context.GetQueryable<GeneralSearchResultItem>()
                     .Where(x.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name);
  query = query.Where(i => (i.Content.Contains(searchTerm) || i.Name.Contains(searchTerm)));

  //Paging
  if (currentPage > 1) {
    query = query.Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize);
  }

  query = query.Take(pageSize);
  return query.GetResults();
  }
}
```

When I run the above code I get the following:

```
myResults.TotalSearchResults = 31
myResults.Count() = 0
```

The correct results should be zero items returned because all of the items are security restricted.  So `myResults.Count() = 0` is correct.  However the `TotalSearchResults = 31` is wrong.

Does `TotalSearchResults` ignore Sitecore security?

Answer (score 0):

TotalSearchResults return whatever items count kept from the index actually satisfy your query. If both security-protected and free items are within index - then it will operate against that set (and I think that is what you are getting). No security data comes into indexes by default.

What does matter indeed - is the actual way how you do index items and what you place there. You may consider from the following options to fit your case:

1. Avoid placing security-protected items at all (not the best scenario)
2. Placing both free and items with additional security data (you may specify in computed field, for example) and add additional clause to filter and select only free items. You may consider index a field from Standard Template called __Security that has pipe separated security settings for that item
3. Include (external, not from index) security check into your Linq query as an additional clause (leaving index untouched itself as is), but that does not seem nice from performance point of view and need to think well big numbers cases (unlike previous point where security stored in the index and resolved by Lucene query)

Comment: Ok - so I guess my question is this then - how do I get the total results count for my query (taking security in to account)? Let's say that I have 100 items that match a particular query, but only 24 of them are available to the anonymous user.  And I am using a page size of 10.  Somehow I need to be able to find out that the total number of results is 24 - not 100.  How can I do that?

Comment: How do you configure your index? Can you add custom computed field into it with security, as little as bit saying wither it is protected or not (or actual roles that are allowed access for more complex cases)?

Comment: I could, but from what I can tell Sitecore 7 has something built in to it that allows you to take security in to account automatically without any extra custom coding.  If you look at the second answer on this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683487/indexing-sitecore-item-security-and-restricting-returned-search-results) you will see what I am talking about.  When I create the SearchContext you have the ability to say whether or not you want to enable the security check.  The default is to enable the security check.

Comment: The Security Check works on the query.  It only returns items that match the security check.  So the query itself does return only 24 results (from my example above).  However the TotalSearchResults property does not seem to take security in to account.

Comment: I do not have a chance to see how it works in SOLR at the moment only Lucene is available. I can see there is no security data there. What comes into my mind is to include (external, not from index) security check into your Linq query as an additional clause (leaving index itesef as it is), but that does not seem nice from performance point of view

Comment: Solr will behave the same as Lucene. Security is applied afterwards. This will effect totals and facet counts. All Martin's points above are very valid.

Comment: Ok - then I am very confused.  When you create the search context you can specify SearchSecurityOptions.EnableSecurityCheck.  What exactly does that do?  I was assuming that meant that you could tell the query whether or not you want to check security or not when performing the query.

Comment: The flag tells sitecore whether or not to run that pipeline after the results have been retrieved (ie filter them out). I think this option will be removed as it is confusing for exactly the reasons you mention.

Comment: If you store the ACLs as part of the record (linked above) you can do the security as a query filter which will give you correct totals and facet counts but this is still not perfect

Comment: I see.  So the TotalSearchResults property is not affected by that pipeline that is run afterwards - right?  It seems odd to me that you could perform a search and the query would tell you that there are 100 total results, but then when you look at the results.Count you get zero (because of security being applied).  I can't imagine a scenario where I would want to perform a search with Security enabled and then still find out how many results I would have gotten if Security had not been enabled.

Comment: After digging into this more and more, the concerns about counts for results and facets become more apparent. The EnableSecurityCheck tells the pipeline to run, but it doesn't affect facet and total counts so it's invalid. Also, Pre 8.0, the pipeline fails due to a case sensitive string compare that always fails (if ("sitecore" == "Sitecore") type check). It looks like this problem is the reason this question exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683487/indexing-sitecore-item-security-and-restricting-returned-search-results

Comment: To @MartinMiles comment about the security flag being removed in the future: It's interesting they would remove it when they just fixed it in 8.0. Although, it would make sense to just get rid of it since it technically creates more issues.